# How I simulate this in CST Studio?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, computational-physics, software, radio-frequency, microwaves

I am trying to simulate this coaxial transmission line setup for EMI shielding. Placed the Aluminium sample as seen below (in the middle).
I am new on this software, learned simulating the coaxial cable, but after adding the sample its showing peculiar results.
The em field lines are getting blocked at the sample. (see below)
while in experiment signals are reaching on port 2.
(thickness of aluminium: 0.5 mm)
(freq: 4 GHz)[image]

Comment: What was the magnitude of the measured $S_{21}$ in the physical experiment?

Comment: Can you share a photo of the physical sample you tested?

Answer (score 3):

The skin depth in aluminum at 4 GHz is about 1.3 um (calculated [here](https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-skin-depth.aspx)).

So it's not surprising that an aluminum block of thickness 0.5 mm shorting together the two conductors of your coaxial transmission line can completely block the signal.

The question is, why did you see nonzero transmission in the real world experiment?

Without knowing the actual physical arrangement you tested, I'd suggest you consider:

- Was the real sample making good electrical contact to both the inner and outer conductors (considering also the oxide layer likely present on the aluminum surface)?
- Was there any seam at all between the aluminum sample and the inner or outer conductor?